# Second thread is not reached

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to start 2 threads, one for tcp and one for udp

```
package com.main;

import com.utility.HibernateUtil;

public class ServerStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Reach 1");
        Thread tcp = new Thread(new TcpServerStarter());
        tcp.start();
        System.out.print("Reach 2");
        Thread udp = new Thread(new UdpServerStarter());
        System.out.print("Reach 3");
        HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.print("Reach 4");
    }

    public static class TcpServerStarter extends Thread{

        public TcpServerStarter(){
            new TcpServer(8500).run();
        }
    }

    public static class UdpServerStarter extends Thread{

        public UdpServerStarter(){
            new UdpServer(1000).run();
        }
    }
}
```

Only "reach 1" is printed. I read that this may occur if i have single core, however i have 2 cores.

Comment: You have not started udp! add udp.start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code into method called `run()` instead of calling it from the constructor (calling the `run()` will block the execution)

```
public static class TcpServerStarter extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new TcpServer(8500).run();
    }
}

public static class UdpServerStarter extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new UdpServer(1000).run();
    }
}
```

}

If the `UdpServer` and `TcpServer` already extends `Thread` or implements `Runnable`, you can start them directly by the `start()` method w/o creating the wrapper classes.

Answer (score 2):

You only create udp thread but not really start it. Add this:

```
    udp.start();
```

Secondly you start the loop directly from the constructor instead of run method. Change to:

```
public static class TcpServerStarter implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        new TcpServer(8500).run();
    }
 }
```

And similarly for the UdpServerStarter.

Comment: @Lundira : there was another problem, see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `new TcpServer(8500).run()`; in TcpServerStarter's constructor

It starts running the tcpServer in the MAIN  thread.
I'm guessing that it just serves forever and this is why it doesn't reach any of the following code.

Also what Zbynek said : you didn't start the udp thread.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing too much your code, this one works. I am not sure what is your specific implementation fo TcpServer or UdpServer looks like. So implemented some dummy ones for now. I see that all the print outs print as expected.

```
package network;


class TcpServer implements Runnable{
    TcpServer(int port){

}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Thread printing:" + i + "tid:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
  }
}


class UdpServer implements Runnable{
    UdpServer(int port){

    }

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Thread printing:" + i + "tid:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

}

```
public class ServerStarter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Reach 1");
    Thread tcp = new Thread(new TcpServerStarter());
    tcp.start();
    System.out.print("Reach 2");
    Thread udp = new Thread(new UdpServerStarter());
    System.out.print("Reach 3");
    //HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
    System.out.print("Reach 4");
}

public static class TcpServerStarter extends Thread{

    public TcpServerStarter(){
        new TcpServer(8500).run();
    }
}

public static class UdpServerStarter extends Thread{

    public UdpServerStarter(){
        new UdpServer(1000).run();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A thread object must be started so that the execution of the corresponding `Thread` can be initiated.

I see in your code below code

```
System.out.print("Reach 1");
Thread tcp = new Thread(new `TcpServerStarter`());
```

Till now you have not yet called the `tcp.start()`. Till now you have created a new object of `Thread.java` which is OK but the main problem I feel is with the constructor of `TcpServerStarter.java` the code written it it prevents the flow of execution of your `main method` ahead.

See **`TcpServerStarter.java`  class is a Thread** itself as it extends `Thread.java`. should `override run method` in your `TcpServerStarter.java` You Should move the code from the constructor to the run() method. Instead of creating the objects of `Thread.java modify the code as below.

```
Thread tcp = new `TcpServerStarter`();
```

Then you need to call start on the Thread object you have created.

```
tcp.start()
```

Similarly you need to modify the code including the usage of `UdpServerStarter`.